Can use BC547 instead of S8050

Can I use BC547 instead of S8050 in this circuit?

What is the source of the image? Can you provide a hyperlink for context please?

Welcome! How does the datasheets compare between them?

Yes, you can use BC547 instead of S8050 in this circuit. But you have to remember that BC547 will have a different pinout than S8050.  So keep that in mind when you decide to build this circuit.

@Andyaka Sure,https://youtu.be/m0S-al2jIgY?si=NjOrIA_nNVYLrEYW

@G36 Thanks, I will do
